# Nodeclipse - Cannot find solution for GC error

Tags: java, node.js, eclipse, garbage-collection

I am suddenly having constant GC errors and Java heap space errors in the Eclipse IDE as of about a day and a half ago. It is making it impossible to get my work done. The IDE simply stops responding for several minutes and then starts crashing with GC errors. These issues start happening roughly 2 minutes into the IDE starting.

These errors occur while just opening files or doing any code changes, not even when running any code. The errors occur for "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection"

I have tried several solutions. I have:

1. I have created a new workspace and imported my 3 projects.
2. I was originally using STS. Since most of my work is with nodejs at the moment, I downloaded a fresh version of Nodeclipse.
3. I have adjusted the values in the eclipse.ini file. I have adjusted the memory values and the required java version. My current ini file looks like this:

.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
nodeclipse.package.enide.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

The issues continue to persist regardless of what I do. Does anyone have any solutions for me? This issue seems to be completely independent from my eclipse installations and workspaces.

Here are a list of the errors I've received over the past hour:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.092
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/resources/icons/boot-icon.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/resources/icons/boot-icon.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.108    
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/resources/icons/boot-icon.png".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/resources/icons/boot-icon.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:77)
... 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.108
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/resources/icons/boot-icon.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot/resources/icons/boot-icon.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
... 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.139
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290) 
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.139
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:77)
...     
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.139
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290) 
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.310
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
... 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.310
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:77)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-06 08:59:17.310
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui/icons/full/obj16/spring_explorer_obj.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-06 09:43:19.836
!MESSAGE Unhandled error
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.newEvent(JobListeners.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.done(JobListeners.java:149)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-06 09:43:34.407
!MESSAGE Unhandled error
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.newEvent(JobListeners.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.done(JobListeners.java:149)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-04-06 09:43:35.006
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setStyle(TextLayout.java:3081)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider.updateTextLayout(StyledCellLabelProvider.java:276)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-04-06 09:44:23.621
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setStyle(TextLayout.java:3081)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider.updateTextLayout(StyledCellLabelProvider.java:276)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-06 09:45:08.112
!MESSAGE Unhandled error
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-04-06 09:45:08.121
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-06 09:45:08.127
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-04-06 09:45:09.355
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setStyle(TextLayout.java:3081)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider.updateTextLayout(StyledCellLabelProvider.java:276)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-04-06 09:45:09.516
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setStyle(TextLayout.java:3081)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider.updateTextLayout(StyledCellLabelProvider.java:276)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface.text 4 0 2016-04-06 09:52:51.585
!MESSAGE Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:185)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-06 10:04:39.554
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.isErrorState(Parser.java:5557)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:5687)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-04-06 10:04:39.558
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Requesting JavaScript AST from selection".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.isErrorState(Parser.java:5557)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:5687)
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 0 2016-04-06 10:11:24.908
!MESSAGE Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.compositeRepository
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil$ReflectionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:344)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some eclipse plugins are fairly inefficient and need considerable amounts of memory, especially on large projects or when parsing merged source files.

So 1GB may not be enough.

If bumping up the heap limit to several gigabytes does not fix the  issue then one of the components may simply have a memory leak. In that case you'd have to figure out which one and file a bug for it.
That can be done by taking a heap dump and analyzing which classes hold onto most of the memory.